# Какой падеж выбрать: "не приняла решение" или "не приняла решения"?

Tags: орфография, падежи

Каким будет окончание существительного?

*Организация не приняла (решени**е** / решени**я**) о создании фонда.*

Comment: всем спасибо за старания. но видимо вопрос был некорректным. В моем вопросе глагол принимать стоит в повелительном наклонении "не приним**айте**"! полностью фраза звучит так: "не принимайте решения прежде, чем не изучите проблему". какой падеж надо применить к слову "решение" в данном контексте? я нашла ответ: родительный падеж нужен если в качестве зависимого слова используется местоимение: не допущу этого; не делайте того.

Answer (score 3):

Существительное, относящееся к глаголу с отрицанием, может иметь форму родительного или винительного падежа (new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr). Однако в вашем примере и вне контекста я бы поставил именно **винительный**, чтобы избежать неоднозначности. "Не приняла решения" может пониматься как "не приняла (никакого) решения" (ед. ч.) и как "не приняла (предлагаемые) решения" (мн. ч.).

**Организация не приняла решение о создании фонда.**

Дополнение.

Вне контекста (в качестве заголовка, например) эта фраза воспринимается скорее всего в том смысле, что речь идет о каком-то **конкретном** решении, которое не было принято по какой-то причине.

Если вы, например, хотите опровергнуть слухи о том, что организация приняла **некое** решение о создании фонда, тогда лучше употребить несовершенную форму глагола время и родительный падеж:

**Организация не принимала решения о создании фонда.**

Если вы хотите сделать заголовок нейтральным, то лучше  употребить несовершенную форму глагола и существительное в родительном падеже мн. ч.:

**Организация не принимала решений о создании фонда.**

Answer (score 0):

Не приняла что? Решение – винительный падеж, окончание -е.

Comment: А почему не родительный?

Comment: Потому что принимают кого и что – винительный падеж. Проверить можно в любом толковом словаре.

Comment: При отрицании возможен и винительный, и родительный. См.  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr

Comment: Если Вы посмотрите ответы справочной службы по запросу "не принял", то не встретите варианты с использованием родительного падежа. Также специалисты справочной службы отмечают, что корректны оба варианта, а окончательное решение остаётся за автором. На мой взгляд (лишь на мой субъективный взгляд, я ни к чему не призываю и не утверждаю, что мои слова – истина в последней инстанции), винительный падеж в данном случае как минимум благозвучнее. И да, как Вы правильно отметили, исключает неоднозначность с числом существительного.

Comment: Я тоже за винительный, но ответ должен быть полным.

Answer (score 0):

Выбор зависит от контекста, проясняющего *степень конкретности* "решения". Если речь идёт о конкретном проекте решения под названием "Решение о создании фонда", то обязателен *винительный* падеж, если же речь идёт об абстрактном решении, то при отрицании предпочтителен *родительный* падеж. Примеры:

> Организация не приняла решени**е** о создании фонда, поставленное на
>   голосование с нарушением регламента общего собрания.
>
> Организация не приняла решени**я** о создании фонда, такой вопрос пока не
>   рассматривался.

При полном отсутствии контекста *нейтральный* выбор сделать затруднительно. Например, если вариант из вопроса - заголовок, оторванный от какой-то статьи, то в одном случае (винительный падеж) логичнее предположить, что решение рассматривалось и было отвергнуто, во втором (родительный) - что ожидаемое решение пока не рассматривалось.

Comment: Если вариант из вопроса - заголовок, то я бы во втором случае изменил его форму, например: Организация не **принимала** решения о создании фонда, или Решение о создании фонда организацией не принималось, или Организация **еще** не приняла решения о создании фонда.

Comment: Да, "не принимала" - более ясный вариант. Различия несущественны: винительный падеж намекает на существование формальной процедуры (нужно принять такое-то решение), известной читателю, в случае родительного падежа недоуменный оттенок "никакого / какого-либо решения". Оба варианта по-прежнему возможны.